# How to read and act on cell entry?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a self calculating patch.
Each row of Column K gives a "0" or a "1" and at the bottom "888" which is intended to direct the macro to STOP - End.
Alternatively to "888", and preferred, would be to STOP when cell K36 is reached.

The part of the macro which modifies by copying and pasting cells is working, one row at a time, by manually triggering one of three macros involved.

In the final design, it is intended to step the active cell down Col K, and on reading "0" step down again.
If the active cell reads "1", modify the sheet.
I need the script to progress down column K, reading the "0", "1" or "888".

Is it possible to read the active cell to take the action it directs?

In the 1990's, I created macros in IBM's Lotus 123, and used the following:

```
{IF@CELLPOINTER("CONTENTS")=0}{BRANCH Down}
{IF@CELLPOINTER("CONTENTS")=1}{BRANCH Cycle}
{IF@CELLPOINTER("CONTENTS")=888}{BRANCH QUIT}
```

... where "Down" & "Cycle" were separate macros.

Comment: You want to loop through cells? There are many questions about that on this site and others.

Comment: Have you tried to set a range where the column has the 0,1,888 value, then loop to each cell to that range ? For example, Column B has the value 0,1,888 starts from B2 to B100. So the code something like this : `set rng = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`. Then you loop to each cell in rng `for each cell in rng .... if cell.value = 1 then call macro1, if cell.value = 888 then exit sub .... next cell`

Answer (score 0):

This is a hint, may not count as a complete answer.

So your question is == Run the loop to evaluate each cell in column K for value 0,1,888. If it is 0; go down to next cell. If it is 1; carry some additional procedure. If it is 888 or the cell is K36 skip the loop, exit the macro...

If it so, following is just a hint.

```
Sub test()

Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Set rng = Range("K1:K36")

For Each cl In rng
    If cl.Value = 1 Then
    ' carry additional procedure
    Else
    If cl = 888 Then Exit For
    End If
Next

End Sub
```